# Next / Previous custom post type with custom field category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have custom post type "**news**" with custom field "**category**". In category user can select:

- 0 - all
- 1 - category1
- 2 - category2
- 3 - category3
- 4 - category4

I need on single-news page next and previous link in same category, including the "**all**" category. So for example I'm on post **X** and it is in category ***3***. Next post **Y** (ordered by date of that post) is in category ***0*** (all). If I click on next (page **X**) I should go on page **Y**, but there should be next link not in category ***0*** but in category ***3***.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about re-aranging your structure a little bit, so that instead of using a custom field for the categories, you use a custom taxonomy? Custom taxonomies are a little more conducive to this stuff, and then you can take advantage of tools already built into WordPress, like [get_next_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post).

If you don't know how to instantiate a custom taxonomy, you can [read about them](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies), or use a plugin like [Custom Post Types UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/), which can generate them for you.